# AutoHotKeys || Sending multiple click on the same windows

Tags: autohotkey

i want to automate some program like "trainer" so i don't have to click multiple checkbox on that program..

Here's what i've tried

```
+LButton::
ControlClick, x35 y124, trainer
ControlClick, x35 y138, trainer
return
Escape::ExitApp
```

The problem is, it's only alternating between first control click command, and the second one..
what i expect is that it will click two different place without removing the first click..
Thank you..
I hope my English is understandable.

Comment: Not really much to be done to try to solve this, there's not much to go on. Guess I could give a few guesses. Maybe try adding the [`NA`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/ControlClick.htm#Reliability) option to those control clicks, maybe try sleeping between them, maybe try e.g. the [`Control`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Control.htm) command instead.

Comment: whoaaa thanks, it really worked. i add `SetControlDelay -1` between the control click